# Determine RTDB url in a trigger function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i m bulding a scalable chat app with RTDB and firestore

here is my raw structure of shards

```
SHARD1
    Chats {
        chat01: {
            Info: {
                // some info about this chatroom
            },
            Messages ...
       }, ....
    }
SHARD2...
```

now i have write triggers on all the info nodes of all the shards.

i want get the ID of the shard
**How do i know what shard it actually ran on ?**

[EDIT]

```
console.log(admin.app().name); // it prints "[DEFAULT]" in console
```

Puf and team please help

Answer (score 1):

When a Realtime Database trigger is invoked, the second argument is an [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext) object that contains information about the database and node that was updated.  That object contains a [resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#resource) string, which has what you're looking for.  According to the documentation for that string, it's name property will be formatted as:

```
projects/_/instances/<databaseInstance>/refs/<databasePath>
```

The `databaseInstance` string is what you're looking for.  So, you can just split the string on "/" and take the 4th element of that array:

```
export const yourFunction = functions.database
.instance('yourShard')
.ref('yourNode')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const parts = context.resource.name.split('/')
    const shard = parts[3]
    console.log(shard)
})
```

If all you need is a reference to the location of the change, in order to perform some changes there, you can just use the `ref` property on the [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.datasnapshot) that was delivered in the first argument, and build a path relative to there.

Comment: i have already solved it. it was an easy thing i just missed. i could directly use `yourShard` from a variable and pass it to trigger and to my code. and your approach is also awesome `+1`. THANKS please relook my scalable chat app with firestore and RTDB. i have removed everything other than one question. please relook => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61284283/make-a-scalable-chat-app-with-firebase-firestore-and-rtdb